# jquery .not to stop nav from hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I've seen this topic before but I can't find it...I keep seeing a lot of 5 year old answers that discuss stopPropagation....

I have a menu that pops up when the main-menu-button is clicked. If I click anywhere else on the document, I want the menu to close. If the menu button or the menu is clicked, I don't want this to happen...I've read up on `.not()` but I feel like I'm using it wrong.

I'm not missing a class selector in `nav` - it's html5. It's just popping out my menu as expected but then immediately hiding it once it shows.

Is there something missing here? Thanks!

**show nav** (working)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.main-menu-button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //$('nav').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('nav').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

**hide nav**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', function(){
        $('.main-menu-button').removeClass('active');
        $('nav').hide('fast');
    }).not('.main-menu-button, nav');
});
```

**html**

```
<header>
<h1>Jimmy's Junk</h1>
<img src = 'http://localhost/inv/img/framework/menu.png' class = 'main-menu-button'>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href = 'http://localhost/inv'>dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href = '#'>reports</a></li>
        <li><a href = '#'>settings</a></li>
        <?=$admin?>
        <li><a href = 'http://localhost/inv/modules/login/php/logOut.php'>log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div class = 'clear'></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML code too please?

Comment: I added it with the other script just in case :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).not('.main-menu-button, nav')) {
    $('nav').hide('fast');
  }
});
```

Comment: I see why this works but shouldn't `.not` work as well in the way I'm implementing? I'm asking because I've seen it used in a similar fashion...unless I'm just crazy lol..that's possible too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have called .on on the full set, and after you've narrowed them down. $(document).not().on() could work, but if your DOM changes meanwhile, your event will not trigger.